# How do I push An instance of a c++ class wrapped with swig onto a lua stack?

Tags: c++, lua, stack, swig

I have a class that is wrapped with swig, and registered with lua. I can create an instance of this class in a lua script, and it all works fine.

But say I have an instance of a class made in my c++ code with a call to new X, and I have la lua_state L with a function in it that I want to call, which accepts one argument, an instance of X... How do I call that function. Here is (some) of the code in question (I've omitted the error handling stuff):

main.cpp

```
class GuiInst;
extern "C"
{
    int luaopen_engine (lua_State *L);
}

int main()
{
    GuiInst gui=new GuiInst;
    lua_State *L=luaL_newstate();
    luaopen_engine(L); //this is swigs module
    int error=luaL_loadfile(L,"mainmenu.lua")||
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    lua_getglobal(L,"Init");
    //Somehow push gui onto lua stack...
    lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0));
    lua_close(L);
}
```

mainmenu.lua

```
function Init(gui)
    vregion=gui:CreateComponent("GuiRegionVertical");
end
```

At the moment all I have found that can work is to expose some functionality from the swig generated cpp file, and call that. This is bad for a few reasons... It won't work if I have multiple modulles and I had to change the default linkage specification in the swig file (using -DSWIGRUNTIME=).

I add the following to main.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
    struct swig_module_info;
    struct swig_type_info;
    int luaopen_engine (lua_State *L);
    swig_module_info *SWIG_Lua_GetModule(lua_State* L);
    void SWIG_Lua_NewPointerObj(lua_State* L,void* ptr,swig_type_info *type, int own);
    swig_type_info *SWIG_TypeQueryModule(swig_module_info *start,swig_module_info *end,const char *name);
}
//and then to push the value...
SWIG_Lua_NewPointerObj(L,gui,SWIG_TypeQueryModule(SWIG_Lua_GetModule(L),SWIG_Lua_GetModule(L),"GuiInst *"),0);
```

That gets a pointer to the module, then a pointer to the type, then calls swigs function to register it. It was an unreasonable thing to have to dig into a file that's not supposed to be human readable (so it says at the top of the file) and is just MESSY! (but it does work!)

Surely theres a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

PS from a high level pov what I want is to have lua not refcount the Gui components which are created by the Object Factory in GuiInst, in case I'm going about this wrong. This is my first time exposing functionality to a scripting language apart from some very simple (and non-swig) python modules, so I'm prepared to take advice.

Thanks for any advice!

---

Response to comment by RBerteig

GuiInst's contructor is #defined to private when swig runs to prevent lua constructing instances of it, so that won't work for me. What I was trying to prevent was the following (in lua):

```
r=engine.GuiRegionVertical()
r:Add(engine.GuiButton())
```

which would call "g=new GuiButton" then register it with the GuiRegionVertical (which needs to store a pointer for various reasons), then call "delete g", and the GuiRegionVertical is left with a dangling pointer to g.

I suspect what really needs to happen is that GuiRegionVertical::Add(GuiButton*) should increment the ref count of the GuiButton*, and then GuiRegionVertical's destructor should decrement the refcounts of all of its contents, though i'm not sure how this should be done with swig.

That would remove the need for the private constructors, the Gui Object Factory and the nasty externs.

Am I going about this Wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWIG:Lua - Passing a c++ instance as a lua function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455552/swiglua-passing-a-c-instance-as-a-lua-function-parameter)

Comment: @NicolBolas: How can this question be a duplicate? It's three years older than that one :). Thanks for the link tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple and direct answer, that may not be the most efficient answer. SWIG produces wrappers for manipulating objects from the scripting language side. For objects, it also synthesizes a wrapped constructor. So, the direct solution is to just let the Lua interpreter call SWIG's constructor to create the new object.

For the wrapped `engine.GuiInst` class, you almost certainly can do something like:

```
int main()
{
    lua_State *L=lua_open();
    luaopen_engine(L); //this is swigs module
    int error=luaL_loadfile(L,"mainmenu.lua")||
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

    luaL_dostring(L, "Init(engine.new_GuiInst())");

    lua_close(L);
}
```

For a one-shot case like script startup, the penalty of running a string constant through luaL_dostring() is not bad at all. I'd look harder to avoid it in an event callback or an inner loop, however.

It does seem like there ought to be a way to convert a pointer directly into a wrapped object, I'm not spotting it in my own handful of SWIG generated wrappers.

**Edit:** Of course, the Lua fragment can be decomposed to API calls that get the engine table global on the stack, extract from it the `new_GuiInst` member, call it, then call the global `Init`, but the little bit of efficiency comes at the cost of some clarity.

As for dealing with objects that shouldn't be constructed by accident in user code, as the clarified question indicates, my first impulse would be to let SWIG generate the constructor function, keep a private reference if needed later, and remove it from the table. Even a C module is (usually) just a table whose members contain function values. Being implemented in C doesn't make them read-only unless extra effort is taken.

So, you could always retrieve the value of `engine.new_GuiInst` and park it in the registry (see [`luaL_ref()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_ref) and the discussion in [section 3.5 of the Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.5) of the pseudo-index `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` for the details) for later use. Then, before letting any user code run, simply do the equivalent of `engine.new_GuiInst = nil`. I should note that for the C data types I've been playing with most recently, SWIG created two constructors for each type, named `new_TYPE` and `TYPE`. Both were visible in the module's table, and you would want to set both names to `nil`. If have much less experience with SWIG wrapping C++ classes, and the result may differ...

You might want to check and review the whole content of the `engine` table returned by SWIG, and create a proxy object that contains only the methods you want available to your users. You can also change the [environment](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.9) seen by the user script so that it only has the proxy available, and names the proxy `engine` as well. There has been a fair amount of discussion of [sandboxing](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) user scripts on the [Lua list](http://www.lua.org/lua-l.html) and at the [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/).

Comment: Thanks for the response (and its speed), I've updated my question as there's not enough space in the comments.
I'd vote up your answer but my rating isn't high enough yet.

Comment: Thanks again, some good advice there, particularly WRT the proxy objects. I fiddled with luaL_ref a little while ago but it didn't seem to share objects between lua_States (as implied by http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.html) so I moved on.

Comment: No its not for sharing between states. Its a way to hold references to objects from the C side so that they can be found again, and so they don't get collected as garbage. Its also the recommended way to put a Lua value in a C struct, treating the int from luaL_ref() as you would a pointer.

Comment: Fair enough. It was the "a library that uses such variables cannot be used in multiple Lua states" from that page that mislead me, but I think I see what that is trying to convey now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Better late then never, and this solution will help other people.

```
void handle_web_request(WebRequest *request, WebResponse *response)
{
  lua_getfield(rackam->lua_state, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "handle_web_request");
  SWIG_Lua_NewPointerObj(rackam->lua_state, request, SWIGTYPE_p_WebRequest, 0);
  SWIG_Lua_NewPointerObj(rackam->lua_state, response, SWIGTYPE_p_WebResponse, 0);
  lua_call(rackam->lua_state, 2, 0);
}
```

this code must be inside %{}% blocks in your .i file, because SWIGTYPE_p_WebRequest is

```
#define SWIGTYPE_p_WebResponse swig_types[6]
```

and swig_types[6] is

```
static swig_type_info *swig_types[12];
```

which means that swig_types is only accessable from the C++ file from which it is defined.

this particular snippet is sending in two of my wrappered pointers, so calling handle_web_request(request, response) from the C++ side of things will run the global lua function "handle_web_request" and pass it my two pointers, with the SWIG magic applied.

Comment: A [more complete version of this answer can be found here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455552/swiglua-passing-a-c-instance-as-a-lua-function-parameter/9455942#9455942)